# Need of fsck and broken system after that

Tags: kubuntu, filesystem, disk, fsck, initramfs

I have reinstalled kubuntu on a laptop two days ago. The Win 8.1 was malfunctioning with 100% disk usage and there was no solution to it. It also started behaving strangely, like sudden lags etc. 
So after a few sessions the kubuntu stopped booting and made me run the fsck. Did that, got some errors, fixed them by hitting "y". Rebooted the system and now I am stuck at flashing cursor on the black screen after the kubuntu logo. When I start the terminal I see tty1 and login line which is flashing as well so I can write there just in the meantime when it's visible. The frequency is pretty high.

OK I have realized I should have used fsck.ext4 instead. My fault. Reinstalled kubuntu. Everything fine...after two days the same again. Running fsck.ext4. Yea worked but messed up plasma and kwin. I can probably reinstall some stuff again but I am afraid it will repeat. Booting into initramfs etc, etc...

I suppose it might be that the hard disk is broken but not sure. Any tips or experience with this? I would like to know the reason. If I should replace the disk or what?

The Disks tool (used live CD) showed that the disk health is OK. 50 bad sectors.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: 50 bad sectors suggest the drive is failing.

Comment: I have no experience in this so is it too much? I mean the tool is saying OK :D. But yea I am afraid it's the disk after all cause this repeating fs corruption seems like happening somehow randomly.

Comment: It isn't too much in absolute terms but if the number increases even by a few it indicates the problem is worsening and it'll give the errors you're experiencing from time to time.

Comment: Hmm I see, well I wonder now if I should give it another shot or not :D.

Comment: It's up to you. A failing drive is most likely the cause as commented before.

Comment: I understand, that you very much for your help. I fixed the plasma so I will give it some time and watch the disk status + wait for another corruption of fs :D. Will probably end up replacing the disk anyway.